# STRIPE Checkout - How can I upgrade my PHP & JQuery code?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I hope someone can help me with this stuff.

This is my PHP code with Stripe: https://stripe.com/it integration.

I wanted to know how i can upgrade it to the new version.
I tried to read the Stripe main website, but I didn't understand how I can upgrade the code.

Thank you for help.

[screenshot error that need upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROwXY.png)

```php
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$clear=0;
$message="Acquistando tutti e 3 i prodotti &egrave; possibile vincere un <a href=\"white_pass.html\" target=\"_blank\">&laquo;White-Pass&raquo;</a>.";

$testing=0;
if (isset($_GET["my_password_secret"])) $testing=1;

$products=array(
                array("Mascherina", "img/mascherina.png", 6),
                array("Cappellino", "img/cappellino.png", 8),
                array("T-Shirt", "img/t-shirt.png", 12)
);

if ($testing == 1) {
    $stripe = [
    "secret_key" => "sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "publishable_key" => "pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    ];
}else{
    $stripe = [
      "secret_key"      => "sk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "publishable_key" => "pk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    ];
}

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
    
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {

    $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
    $cash = (int)$_POST["amount"];
    $for_input = htmlentities($_POST["for_input"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $object=explode("#", $for_input);
    
    $t="";
    
    foreach ($object as $ob) {
        
        if (strstr($ob, "|")) {
            $ob2=explode("|", $ob);
            $price_=(int)$ob2[2] * (int)$ob2[1];
            $t.="<tr><td>".$ob2[0]."</td><td>".$ob2[1]."</td><td>&euro;".$price_."</td></tr>";
        }
        
    }

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        'email' => $email,
        'source'  => $token,
    ]);

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'description' => $for_input,
        'amount'   => $cash * 100,
        'currency' => 'eur',
    ]);

    $message="Pagamento di &euro;".$cash.", effettuato con successo!";
    $clear=1;

    $mail_msg="
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Hai acquistato su WhiteHouseIta.com</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>L'Acquisto &egrave; avvenuto con successo!</p>
    <table width='80%'>
    <tr>
    <th style='text-align:left'>Oggetto</th>
    <th style='text-align:left'>Quantit&agrave;</th>
    <th style='text-align:left'>Prezzo</th>
    </tr>
    ".$t."
    <tr>
    <td>
    &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
    &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
    &nbsp;
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Totale
    </td>
    <td>
    &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
    &euro;".$cash."
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Per procedere pi&uacute; velocemente alla spedizione, contatti il seguente numero su whatsapp: +39 3279361676 (Mattia).<br>
    Grazie per aver acquistato!<br><br>
    Whitehouseita Team.
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <info@whitehouseita.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: info@whitehouseita.com' . "\r\n";
    
    mail($email, "Hai acquistato su WhiteHouseIta.com", $mail_msg, $headers);
    
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>White House - Shop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
  
<style>
body {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.show-cart li {
  display: flex;
}
.card {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.card-img-top {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  align-self: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body translate="no" >
  <!-- Nav -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top bg-faded">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" id="button-carrello" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cart">Carrello (<span class="total-count"></span>)
            </button>
            <button class="clear-cart btn btn-danger">Svuota Carrello</button>
            <?php

            if ($testing == 1) {
                
            ?>
            
            <font color="yellow" size="4">&nbsp;Test Mode: On</font>
            
            <?php
                
            }

            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Main -->
<div class="container">

<h4 style="font-size:18px;padding-bottom:15px">
<?php echo $message; ?>
</h4>

    <div class="row">

<?php

for ($i=0; $i<count($products); $i++) {

echo "
<div class=\"col\">
  <div class=\"card\" style=\"width: 20rem;\">
      <img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"".$products[$i][1]."\" alt=\"Foto del prodotto\">
      <div class=\"card-block\">
          <h4 class=\"card-title\">".$products[$i][0]."</h4>
          <p class=\"card-text\">Prezzo: €".$products[$i][2]."</p>
          <a href=\"#\" data-name=\"".$products[$i][0]."\" data-price=\"".$products[$i][2]."\" class=\"add-to-cart btn btn-primary\">Aggiungi al Carrello</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
";

}

?>

    </div>
</div>

  
 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="cart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Carrello</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

<form method="post">

      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="show-cart table">
          
        </table>
        <div>
Totale: €<span class="total-cart"></span>
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="0">
<input name="for_input" type="hidden" value="0">
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="close_modal" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>

        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
          class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
          data-name="White House"
          data-description="Paga con Carta di Credito"
          //data-amount="0"
          data-locale="auto"
          data-currency="eur"
          data-label="Paga Adesso">
        </script>

     </div>

</form>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script id="rendered-js">

var shoppingCart = function () {

  cart = [];

  function Item(name, price, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.count = count;
  }

  function saveCart() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  }

  function loadCart() {
    cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
  }
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") != null) {
    loadCart();
  }

  var obj = {};

  obj.addItemToCart = function (name, price, count) {
    for (var item in cart) {
      if (cart[item].name === name) {
        cart[item].count++;
        saveCart();
        return;
      }
    }
    var item = new Item(name, price, count);
    cart.push(item);
    saveCart();
  };

  obj.setCountForItem = function (name, count) {
    for (var i in cart) {
      if (cart[i].name === name) {
        cart[i].count = count;
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  obj.removeItemFromCart = function (name) {
    for (var item in cart) {
      if (cart[item].name === name) {
        cart[item].count--;
        if (cart[item].count === 0) {
          cart.splice(item, 1);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    saveCart();
  };

  obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function (name) {
    for (var item in cart) {
      if (cart[item].name === name) {
        cart.splice(item, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    saveCart();
  };

  obj.clearCart = function () {
    cart = [];
    saveCart();
  };

  obj.totalCount = function () {
    var totalCount = 0;
    for (var item in cart) {
      totalCount += cart[item].count;
    }
    return totalCount;
  };

  obj.totalCart = function () {
    var totalCart = 0;
    for (var item in cart) {
      totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
    }
    return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
  };

  obj.listCart = function () {
    var cartCopy = [];
    for (i in cart) {
      item = cart[i];
      itemCopy = {};
      for (p in item) {
        itemCopy[p] = item[p];

      }
      itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
      cartCopy.push(itemCopy);
    }
    return cartCopy;
  };

  return obj;
}();

$('.add-to-cart').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
  displayCart();
});

$('.clear-cart').click(function () {
  shoppingCart.clearCart();
  displayCart();
});

function ClearMyCart() {
    shoppingCart.clearCart();
    displayCart();
}

function displayCart() {
  var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
  if (cartArray.length == 0) {
      $('#close_modal').click();
  }
  var output = "";
  var for_input = "";
  for (var i in cartArray) {
    for_input += cartArray[i].name + "|" + cartArray[i].count + "|" + cartArray[i].price + "#";
    output += "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" +
    "<td>(" + cartArray[i].price + ")</td>" +
    "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">-</button>" +
    "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>" +
    "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">+</button></div></td>" +
    "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">X</button></td>" +
    " = " +
    "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" +
    "</tr>";
  }
    
    if (shoppingCart.totalCart() == 0) {
        $('#button-carrello').hide();
    }else{
        $('#button-carrello').show();
    }
    
  $('.show-cart').html(output);
  $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
  $('input[name=amount]').val(shoppingCart.totalCart());
  $('input[name=for_input]').val(for_input);
  $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
}

$('.show-cart').on("click", ".delete-item", function (event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
  displayCart();
});

$('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function (event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
  displayCart();
});

$('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function (event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
  displayCart();
});

$('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function (event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  var count = Number($(this).val());
  shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
  displayCart();
});

displayCart();
</script>

<?php

if ($clear == 1) {
    
    echo "<script>ClearMyCart();</script>";
    
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dovresti leggere e usare questa [**guida alla migrazione**](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration) (Non riesco a trovare la guida alla migrazione in italiano sul sito web di Stripe)

Comment: You should read and use this [**migration guide**](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration)

Comment: Anche alcune note di riferimento:
1) Usare [**PHPmailer**](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) e non la funzione `mail` nativa di PHP
2) [Questo post](https://stripe.com/it-gb/guides/european-checkouts-in-2020) (Italiano) può esserti molto utile per individuare problemi con il tuo Checkout.
Buona fortuna.